# “Verb1 preposition1 and verb2 preposition2” VS. “Verb1 and verv2 preposition2”?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, verbs, parallelism

When we have two verbs followed by a preposition separately, should we omit the first one?

> - I am addicted **to** and pleased **with** the new drug.
> - I am addicted and pleased **with** the new drug.

In what cases do we omit the first preposition and what cases we keep them both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your second sentence is not idiomatic, as it means you are saying "addicted *with*" which (as you know) is not the normal collocation.  If you need two different prepositions, then you have to apply the proper preposition to each.  Example:

> In order to find the treasure, you must **gather up** and **bind together** all of the parts of the map which I have scattered around the garden.

Still, your first sentence is a little odd, mostly  because of the unlikely juxtaposition of "addicted to" and "pleased with".  Phrasing it this way suggests you consider the addiction to also be a positive consequence.

In cases like this where you're stuck between an awkward phrasing and an incomplete phrasing, it may be best to rephrase it as a longer sentence, to accurately convey your meaning.  For example:

> **Although** I am pleased with the new drug, I am addicted to it.